# $compile:tpload] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.3/$compile/tpload? Unidentified partial in angular eventhough path url is correct

Tags: angularjs

I ran the link on the browser and it worked but it never loads up in the application.

Error in my console:

Error: [$compile:tpload] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.3/$compile/tpload?p0=app%2Fviews%2Fpartials%2Fpartial-index.html&p1=undefined&p2=undefined

my app.js:

```js
(function(){
 'use strict';

 var app = angular.module('app',[
  'ui.router',
  'ngCookies'
 ]);

    app.config([
     '$stateProvider',
        '$urlRouterProvider',
        '$httpProvider',
        '$locationProvider',
        'staticData',
        authConfig
    ]);
    function authConfig(
        $stateProvider,
        $urlRouterProvider,
        $httpProvider,
        $locationProvider,
        staticData ) {

        $stateProvider.state('index', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: 'app/views/partials/partial-index.html'
        });

  

        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
        $httpProvider.interceptors.push('requestInterceptor');

      

    app.run([
     '$rootScope', 
     '$state', 
     'authService', 
     authRun
    ]);

    function authRun($rootScope, $state, authService){
     $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState){
      if(toState.data && toState.data.accessLevel){
       var user = authService.getUserData(); 
       if(!(toState.data.accessLevel & user.role)){
        event.preventDefault(); 
        $state.go('index'); 
        return; 
       }
      }
     })
    }
})();
```

My directory:

[image: My directory]

Comment: I think you got 404 error - Open developer tools and check the network tab, see what path angularjs is trying to fetch the view

Comment: @AlonEitan I actually get a 304 in the terminal. So I dded a feature to clear my cache and it still does not work.

Comment: But are you sure the server return the correct view? Maybe your server return the default document instead (`index.html`)? This is very hard to debug without knowing the server configuration and the content of the views

Comment: @AlonEitan in my index.html, I have the code for my navbar and <div ui-view></div>. It only renders the code in the index.html. However, if I user template instead of templateUrl, it shows the string

Comment: So I suspect it has to do with the relative path. My last suggestion is to make sure to use the relative path to the file form `index.html`, so if that file is under `views`, try and change the path to `templateUrl: 'partials/partial-index.html'` (I can't think of anything else - Sorry)

Comment: @AlonEitan: Your response was a life saver. I just deployed an angularjs based application and was getting this error. After combing the web a couple times, I stumbled on this solution and it was the answer to my challenge.